# Unable to insert from sqlalchemy to mysql

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert a row into a table of a mysql db with sql alchemy, but when I insert and go to the database check the data, I see nothing.

This is my code:

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.sql import table, column, select, update, insert
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

```
engine = create_engine(
      "mysql://user:password@host/schema")
connection = engine.connect()

metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
prices = Table('historical_prices', metadata, autoload=True)
i = insert(prices)
i = i.values({
    "date": my_date, 
    "instrument": msg['instrument'],
    "open": msg['candles'][0]['openAsk'],
    "high": msg['candles'][0]['highAsk'],
    "low": msg['candles'][0]['lowAsk'],
    "close": msg['candles'][0]['closeAsk'],
    "volume": msg['candles'][0]['volume']
    })
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
session.execute(i)
```

I receive no error message from this code.
How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know if it's because you've left it out, but you're missing a `session.commit()`.

Comment: @univerio thanks! this solved the issue. Would you like to answer the question? So I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

As the right answer haven't been posted yet by the original person who came up with it.
I am going forward to do so.

> I don't know if it is because You've left it out, but You're missing a
>   `session.commit()`

Hopefully this answer will be more visible for next people with the same problem.